# The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I want to use HttpWebRequest to post a file to the server:

```
private void testUpload()
{
    FileStream source = File.Open(@"C:\test.txt", FileMode.Open);

    var request = 
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://example.com/Project/"));
    request.Method = "POST";

   request.BeginGetResponse(DataUploadCompleted, request);
}

private void DataUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
    var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
}
```

I got this exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

When I access: "http://example.com/Project/", the page shows:

```
Directory Listing Denied

This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.
```

---

However, I already chmod 777 for the folder: project and allow IIS user to upload files on it (full permission).

Why I got that exception?

I searched for a solution. Some people advices to use:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
request.Credentials = myCred;
```

Is myusername and mypassword the account of the FTP?

If I have to use FTP account, then I don't like that. Can I use some other credentials rather then FTP account? Because I don't want to give the ftp account and people will access on my server.

Comment: you need to set up a default document for the virtual directory.

Comment: what is the default document? how can I set up it up?

Comment: user name is the domain name for example if your domain is mydomain.com your user should be mydomain.com\username does this make sense or if this is truly being done via FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath); ..? then your user name would be the FTP accout user name and ftp password

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I added index.html and i can view the link but I got the same exception

Comment: @DJKRAZE i am sorry, I dont get it. Where can I get that user: mydomain.com\username and password from my hosting?

Comment: There needs to be a file (for instance, an ashx handler) that will handle your file upload. If you're trying to upload to "http://mydomain.com/Project/", then your handler needs to be called to handle the upload.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a permissions issue on the Virtual Directory .. what does the physical file path / folder permissions look like..?

Comment: Brian I will let you handle this one.. ok..

Comment: out of curiosity if you change your code to use a simple uri for example 

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://mydomain.com/"));
what happens.. are you able to connect at least..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE no, it does not work.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll could you please give me a sample how to handle it on the server with ashx handler?

Comment: @devn StackOverflow is not a "give me the code" site, and besides I don't really have the luxury of time to do it. There are a lot of tutorials and examples, like [this one](http://www.fremus.co.za/blog/2009/10/uploading-files-with-a-generic-handler-ashx/), if you search for "file upload ashx" with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add a webpage on the server to handle the uploading.

Answer (score 1):

go to IIS and then open directory browsing and enable it, this should work

Comment: That is no OK because the user will browse the folder and can download eveything

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error for IIS config in the server you want "GetResponse();".

For preventing attack the server by lots of request to Web Api , IIS check user-agent and when there is not user-agent Server return 405 error.

You must set user-agent for example browser user-agent for passing this error.

see this code and use it in your code :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(item.Url);

                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; ; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060917 Firefox/1.9.0.1";
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.Timeout = 1000 * 300;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000 * 300;
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```