# Returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#

At the moment I am trying to make a web crawler and I am stuck with this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Here is my code:

```
Stream receiveStream = null;
url = item1;
HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();
receiveStream = response1.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = null;
if (response.CharacterSet == null)
{
    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
}
else
{
    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
}

html = readStream.ReadToEnd();

response1.Close();
readStream.Close();
```

How can I skip to the next "item1" if I get this error?

Comment: You don't need to skip anything. Can you give us an example of item1?

Comment: item1=https://example.com

Comment: if you don't care anymore as soon as you receive a 501, why not just wrap it in a try/catch?

Comment: item1=http://emaple.com/1.js

Comment: The Default HttpWebRequest is "Get" and I believe the API you are trying to call does not accept GET. Try with POST

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I guess. The URL requires POST request and not GET or HEAD which you'd be sending.

Comment: @Sujith can I have both GET and POST at the same time?

Comment: @Sujith by that logic, PUT and DELETE should also be probed. that makes no sense for a crawler

Comment: No, only one. You cannot have a request of both types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383484/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: can you guys show me a a try {} catch {} in order to switch to post or head?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post